# replace 2 words in a string with php

Tags: php, string, replace, words

How can I do this replace in php, I have a first title which is like this:

> the price **From** example **To** example is 3,

and I want to output the same title also but change like this:

> the price **To** example **From** example is 3,

I use the code below but is not change the second word. I get this:

> the price **To** example **To** example is 3,

`echo str_replace(array("From","To"), array("To","From"), $title);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [strtr](https://php.net/strtr):

```
$newTitle = strtr($title, array("From"=>"To", "To"=>"From"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$phrase  = "the price From example To example is 3";
$texta = array("From", "To");
$textb   = array("To", "From");

$newphrase = str_replace($texta, $textb, $phrase);
```

Comment: This code does the same thing as the original code that was posted.

Comment: need to change the variable location. $newphrase = str_replace($textb, $texta, $phrase);

Comment: i try this but not work for my case, i use the first answer and working as i want. Thank you!

Comment: The output is the price From example From example is 3

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that str_replace will execute its replacing in order with your array and no matter what order you put them in it will always override the first replacement.

First step is you are telling str_replace to find "**From**" and replace with "**To**".  Making your phrase at this point:

> the price From example To example is 3

which becomes

> the price To example To example is 3

Then str_replaces to the next item in your array which is to look for "To" and replace it with "From".  At this point you can probably see the problem.

---

Use ChrisMoll's answer.